# Finding the value of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{k}}{2^{2^{k}}+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Does this weighted sum of reciprocals of Fermat numbers,

$$
F=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^{k}}{2^{2^{k}}+1}
$$

have a nice closed form? Wolfram says it's $1$.

Thanks.

Comment: Mh yeah wolfram gives one, mathematica doesn't evaluate it. thats strange

Comment: I think Wolfram Alpha is adding the numerical approximation automatically, whereas Mathematica doesn't try to guess what you mean. [Here's what I get in Mathematica](http://i.stack.imgur.com/O85cc.png).

Comment: @ZevChonoles I get the same with mathematica, btw there is the command NSum which evaluates Sum numerical and is much faster than Sum

Comment: @Dominic: Great, thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: `NSum` only does numerical sums. If `Sum` cannot find a closed form, it calls `NSum` to compute numerically. Therefore, if you are only looking for a numerical approximation, then `NSum` will always be faster.

Comment: @robjohn by default Sum doesn't call NSum if it can't find a closed form, and only gives back the input as far as i know

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: you are correct. What I was remembering was this from the Mathematica help text: "`N[Sum[...]]` calls `NSum` for sums that cannot be done symbolically." I think my statement about looking for numerical sums is still valid, though.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Hint:

Try to guess and prove a formula for partial sums
$$
S(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2^k}{2^{2^k}+1}.
$$
Here
$$
S(0)=\frac13,\ S(1)=\frac{11}{15},\ S(2)=\frac{247}{255},\ldots
$$
See a pattern for $1-S(n)$?

Comment: Great Observation.Would have given you $20\times (+1)'s$

Comment: Math is often an experimental science. Before deciding on an attack at a problem it may be a good idea to compute a few special cases.

Comment: Perfect. Very clear, thank you.

Comment: @exploringnet: he's got those 20 now :-)

Comment: Great answer, Sir!

Answer (score 19):

This might be another way of looking at Jyrki's hint, but here is the way I did this:
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C0C0C0}{1-\frac1{2-1}+}\frac1{2+1}&=1-\frac2{4-1}\\
1-\frac{2}{4-1}+\frac{2}{4+1}&=1-\frac{4}{16-1}\\
1-\frac{4}{16-1}+\frac{4}{16+1}&=1-\frac8{256-1}\\
1-\frac8{256-1}+\frac8{256+1}&=1-\frac{16}{65536-1}\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
$$

---

**Motivation behind this approach**

One trick to try is [conjugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(algebra)). Noting that
$$
\frac{2^k}{2^{2^k}-1}-\frac{2^k}{2^{2^k}+1}=\frac{2^{k+1}}{2^{2^{k+1}}-1}
$$
we see, using [Telescoping Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^k}{2^{2^k}+1}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{2^k}{2^{2^k}-1}-\frac{2^{k+1}}{2^{2^{k+1}}-1}\right)\\
&=1-\frac{2^n}{2^{2^n}-1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, letting $n\to\infty$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k}{2^{2^k}+1}=1
$$

Comment: +1: Looks like we both want to replace an honest induction with an ellipsis/3dots today. Kids, don't do this at home!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: dots the way things are going this morning, but to say we always use an ellipsis would be hyperbole.

Comment: Going off on a tangent, Rob?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: it's a sine of my old age.

Comment: Very good use of colors.

Answer (score 4):

Use the identity
$$\frac{1}{t+1} = \frac{1}{t-1} - \frac{2}{t^2 -1}.$$