# How is the infinite product 2?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

I found this problem and according to Wolfram Alpha, the answer is 2.

$$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \left (1+\frac{1}{2^{2^n}}\right)$$

Please do the favor of explaining me how the product is 2.

Comment: Write down a partial product, and multiply with $1 - 2^{-2^0}$.

Comment: @SteamyRoot I did check that before posting the question here. On http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922298/closed-form-of-infinite-product-prod-limits-k-0-infty-left1-frac12?rq=1 , none had given an answer which I understood and the person had asked "closed form" which honestly makes no sense to me.

Comment: (double) See the post of *DeepSea* in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922298/closed-form-of-infinite-product-prod-limits-k-0-infty-left1-frac12?noredirect=1&lq=1 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multiply it by $(1-\frac12):$

$$\begin{align}(1-\frac12)P&\vphantom{\cfrac11}=(1-\frac12)(1+\frac12)(1+\frac1{2^2})(1+\frac1{2^4})\dots\\\vphantom{\cfrac11}&=(1-\frac1{2^2})(1+\frac1{2^2})(1+\frac1{2^4})\dots\\\vphantom{\cfrac11}&=(1-\frac1{2^4})(1+\frac1{2^4})\dots\\&=(1-\frac1{2^8})\dots\\&=\vdots\\\vphantom{\cfrac11}&=1\end{align}$$

This uses the fact that $(1-a)(1+a)=(1-a^2)$.

Thus,

$$(1-\frac12)P=1\implies P=2$$

Comment: Nicely presented. (+1)

Comment: @LinuxGeek some missing steps

Comment: @Dr.MV thanks!!

Comment: @LinuxGeek Say, if you don't mind, you should hit the green checkmark button for an answer if you are satisfied by it.  It'll help future users know which answer are good and such.

Answer (score 10):

*(migrated from comment)* In general, for $|x| < 1$ we have

$$ \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1 + x^{2^n}) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-x}. \tag{*}$$

This is essentially the statement that there is a unique binary expansion for each non-negative integer. For the proof, notice that

$$ (1-x)\prod_{n=0}^{N-1} (1 + x^{2^n}) = 1 - x^{2^N}. $$

This can be obtained by applying the formula $(1 - X)(1+X) = 1-X^2$ repeatedly. Now taking $N \to \infty$ you get $\text{(*)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying a sum of $n$ terms by $1+2^{-n}$ will replicate all terms and scale down the replicas by $2^n$.

The partial products are

$$1$$
$$\color{green}{1+\frac12}$$
$$\left(\color{green}{1+\frac12}\right)+\frac14\left(\color{green}{1+\frac12}\right)=\color{blue}{1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18}$$
$$\left(\color{blue}{1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18}\right)+\frac1{16}\left(\color{blue}{1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18}\right)=1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\frac1{16}+\frac1{32}+\frac1{64}+\frac1{128}$$
$$\cdots$$